# Oracle WITH clause create table taking too long

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create a table using the WITH clause  in oracle 11g but the query  takes very long time but if I run the same query without a create statement it executes. anyone else ever came across this issue?

Comment: When you run the query on its own, are you getting *all* of the results back quickly - or just the first page of, say, 50 rows? e.g. in the SQL Developer 'Query Result' window?

Comment: I am getting the results  quickly but saying  50 rows   .

Comment: Right, so if you let the query get all of the rows - keep scrolling down until it says 'all rows fetched', which probably isn't practical; or do a `count(*)` with your query as a subquery - you'll see it taking much longer. Probably the same time as the CTAS, give or take a small amount of overhead. Do you know how many rows you are expecting it to find and insert into the new table?

Comment: about 50  thousand

Comment: it has been running for like  2 hours and has not completed so I had to kill it

Comment: So... it's likely to take 1000 times as long to fetch all of the rows as it did to fetch just 50 rows, though that can vary depending on what the query is doing. And inserting those takes more time - writing takes longer than reading. You may want to look at tuning the query.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to rewrite the WITH query instead of turning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here was to use query hints  specifically hints with index. It cut down the query execution time by 98% . now CTAS running for only 5 minutes down from over 12 hours